# Choosing right node.js server side framework for game development

Tags: javascript, node.js, frameworks, sails.js

I have an idea to create a browser-based game and I struggle to find the right tools to use. I'm a Python/Django developer right now, but I also would like to learn something new and try using node.js for backend. The thing is that there are a lot of frameworks around and I have no idea which one can be the most suitable for game development.

I have read a little bit about sails.js, hapi.js, total.js and others. Many of them sound nice and it is very hard to pick one.

A few of the requirements are:

- Good performance
- Easy use of web sockets
- ORM with migration support (sails.js doesn't have migration support production ready)
- Large community (a lot of packages for common scenarios etc., many questions already answered)

I hope somebody can help me to pick the right tool to use.

Comment: You might want to consider this for SO's sister Software Recommendations site.

Comment: Did you tried this? https://github.com/NetEase/pomelo

Comment: Not yet. Thanks for suggestion, I will take look.